# Bootstrap is not working after partial postback with asp.net update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have some checkbox with bootstrap style sheet "Flat", initially they are showing as expected, they are in between the update panel. When the page partially updated through updatepanel the stylesheet of the Checkbox lost and seems to be not working.
please suggest

Comment: I suggest you give some context and some code so we could understand. With the informations we have, I'm afraid the only suggestion we can make is : well, something wrong, keep digging.

Comment: you should specify a little more the problem , maybe put code to better understand the problem and help you.

Comment: <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chktest" runat="server" class="flat" />
                                              Test                                                         
                                                    </label></div> this is the code for the checkbox and this code comes under the updatepanel. This code works fine in the pageload and after partial page post back its style gone.